# MFMailComposeViewController not displaying recipients for internationalized email

Tags: swift, messageui

Following the [documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller), I was able to successfully pop the MFMailComposeViewController modal up with prefilled email recipients. Well, until I tried to prefil the modal with an internationalized email address with non-ascii characters:

```
    let picker = MFMailComposeViewController()
    picker.setToRecipients(["eai-testé@domain.tld"])
    // ...
```

Surprisingly, when I input the non-ascii email manually, there is no problem with the mail native app. I successfully find a programmatical ugly workaround:

```
        var email = "eai-testé@domain.tld".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)
    var str = "mailto:" + email.unsafelyUnwrapped
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: str).unsafelyUnwrapped)
```

This method won't work with the MFMailComposeViewController since it uses url encoding, which does not make sense for a plain email address. Of course, not using MFMailComposeViewController isn't good, since the workaround doesn't have a predicate to intercept errors and stuff like that.

Comment: [RFC6531](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6531.html) is not widely adopted. That having being said, I agree that if we can enter it manually, we should be able to do programmatically with via `MFMailComposeViewController`, too. Now, whether our mail servers support it or not is a separate question...